# Logrotate and Shell Script

Tags: shell, logrotate

Given logfiles in a directory stamped like this:

```
log_from_2012_08_14-11:57:21_To_2012_09_14-11:56:12.zip
log_from_2012_10_14-11:57:21_To_2012_11_14-11:56:12.zip
```

And given that there are about 155450 files like this, how can I do the following in a simple or efficient way:

Use logrotate, or another tool, to make a folder for each month : mkdir $currentMont = october, for example, and put all of the October, 2012 files there, and so on, for each month.

Comment: These logs span across 2 months, do you want them to be sorted by start time?

Comment: hmmm tht is a example my servers have logs for each 2 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bash script with a couple nested for loops would do the trick.

something like:

```
for year in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 20); do
    for month in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 12); do
        dest = "20${year}-${month}"
        mkdir "$dest"
        mv "log_from_${dest}*" "${dest}";
    done;
done;
```

Clearly you would need to tweak this to your needs.  If there are too many files in one directory you could run into the line glob limit in which case you will have to use `find . | xargs mv` to avoid that problem.

Comment: yep but thank you very much for the help i think the glob limit will pop up almost for sure i can even do a ls in the dir the server just stops ... because of the sorted ability of ls i have to do a ls -f to see files ... imagine a for loop lol